# React AsyncTypeahead using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use the module **React Bootstrap Typeahead** ([original](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead) and [type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) versions) in React using tsx files.

Im using the following versions:

```
"@types/react-bootstrap-typeahead": "3.4.5"
"react-bootstrap-typeahead": "3.4.3"
```

I builded the following **SimpleAsyncExample** class, trying to test the component by always return the same results no matter what the user types, but with a delay in the response...

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {AsyncTypeahead, ClearButton, Token} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

interface State {
  capital: string;
  name: string;
  population: number;
  region: string;
  setValue: (value: State) => void;
}

const options: State[] = [
  { name: 'Alabama', population: 4780127, capital: 'Montgomery', region: 'South', setValue: () => {} },
  { name: 'Alaska', population: 710249, capital: 'Juneau', region: 'West', setValue: () => {} },
  { name: 'Arizona', population: 6392307, capital: 'Phoenix', region: 'West', setValue: () => {} },
  { name: 'Arkansas', population: 2915958, capital: 'Little Rock', region: 'South', setValue: () => {} },
  { name: 'California', population: 37254503, capital: 'Sacramento', region: 'West', setValue: () => {} },
  { name: 'Colorado', population: 5029324, capital: 'Denver', region: 'West', setValue: () => {} },
];

type propTypes = {};
type defaultProps = {
  isLoading: boolean,
  options: State[]
};

export default class SimpleAsyncExample extends React.Component<propTypes, defaultProps> {

  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    options: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AsyncTypeahead
          {...this.state}
          id="typeahead"
          delay={800}
          emptyLabel="No se encontraron resultados"
          ignoreDiacritics={true}
          minLength={3}
          onSearch={this.onSearch}
          placeholder="Insert text to search"
          promptText="Searching"
          searchText="Searching"
          renderMenuItemChildren={(selectedItem: State, props) => {
            return <Token
              active
              disabled={false}
              tabIndex={5}
              href="https://test.com"
              onRemove={() => console.log(props.text)}>
              {selectedItem.name}<ClearButton onClick={() => {}} />
            </Token>;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSearch = (query: string) => {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({isLoading: false, options,});
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

I also configured (as indicated on the documentation) the css import...

```
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead-bs4.css';
```

This app isn't working, doesn't suggest any results.

The thing is that in the test or examples the there is none involving the AsyncTypeahead component and I didn't found any example, so if anyone has a solution, or maybe another module recommendation that work with Bootstrap 4 and React (with Typescript) or a working example that use this library will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ericgio the implementation isn't working, so a solution, another module recommendation or a working example will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the correct `labelKey` field. The value is "label" by default, but in your case there is no "label" field in the options so the filter fails. Setting `labelKey` to "name" fixes the problem:

```
<AsyncTypeahead
  {...this.state}
  id="typeahead"
  delay={800}
  emptyLabel="No se encontraron resultados"
  ignoreDiacritics={true}
  labelKey="name" // <---------- You're missing this
  minLength={3}
  onSearch={this.onSearch}
  placeholder="Insert text to search"
  promptText="Searching"
  searchText="Searching"
/>
```

Note that the input text will still filter the returned results, so entering "cal" will display "California" as a result, but entering "sdfgsdfg" will return an empty result set.

Finally, the `ClearButton` component is not exposed by the library, so you'll see a syntax error when the menu items render.

Comment: adding that line throws the following error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`

Comment: @JulioVillane: Works fine for me? https://codesandbox.io/s/async-typeahead-example-ztkz0

Comment: I had the same error message above but a different situation so I'll add my solution here for future readers.  It was resolved by making my options state variable strongly typed.  I think the underlying type definitions have specific requirements about the types the label field can be, I think in my case that's why it was failing.

Comment: @ericgio the example you gave has an error on line 85

Comment: @unclenorton: You're right. Seems to be a problem with the type definitions. `labelKey` shouldn't be optional.

Comment: I found a workaround to this, anwered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575786/react-bootstrap-typeahead-labelkey-typescript/63576413#63576413