# react-bootstrap-typeahead labelKey Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have the same question as discussed (but never answered) in ericgio's answer to this question [React AsyncTypeahead using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170309/react-asynctypeahead-using-typescript)

There seems to be a problem with the type definitions for **labelKey**

I get the following error from this code:

```
<Typeahead
     id="basic-typeahead-single"
     labelKey="name"
     onChange={this.changeEdgeName}
     options={this.state.streetNames}
     placeholder=""
    />
```

> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TypeaheadProps, context?: any): Typeahead', gave the following error.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.  TS2769

dependencies:

```
"@types/react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^3.4.6",
    
"react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.1",
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a workaround!

I separated the  tag to its own component, in that component the labelKey was not required for some reason.

I have no idea why this works, but it does for me!

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: This is clearly not an answer, please clarify

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by casting as follows:

```
import { Typeahead, TypeaheadLabelKey } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
...

labelKey={'displayName' as TypeaheadLabelKey<string>}
```

Where `displayName` is your labelKey.